# Prove that $\sin(a)$ + $\cos(a)\leq\sqrt{2}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

$$\begin{align*}
\sin (a) + \cos(a) &\leq \sqrt{2}\\
(\sin(a)+ \cos(a))^2 &\leq (\sqrt{2})^2\\
\sin^2(a) + 2\sin(a)\cos(a) + \cos^2(a) &\leq \text{2}
\end{align*}$$
Am I doing it right? I need help.

Comment: This question as written is completely unreadable. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Have I interpreted the question correctly?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Wow, that's what I call a wild guess :'D

Comment: You're doing it sort of right, but backwards.  You have $\sin^2a+\cos^2a = 1$, and $\sin 2a \leq 1$, so $\sin^2a+\cos^2a+\sin2a \leq 2$.  Hence $\sin^2a+2\sin a\cos a+\cos^2a \leq 2$.  Hence $(\sin a+\cos a)^2 \leq 2$.  Hence $\sin a + \cos a \leq \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: It looks like you want to show $|\sin(a)+\cos(a)|\le \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Incidentally, upvoting this because the question seems reasonable, and the asker provided context; it was probably downvoted because of its ungainly appearance?

Comment: @i.m.soloveichik: That also follows, but I figured the OP can modify the last line of reasoning suitably. :-)

Comment: @BrianTung It was most likely downvoted because it was completely unreadable in the OPs version. (See the revision history)

Comment: thanks brian but can you post it as an answer plz to follow steps

Comment: @AlexR: That's sort of what I meant by "ungainly appearance." :-)

Comment: By the way, @ZevChonoles, that is an *inspired* piece of mind-reading and editing.  I want to upvote that edit.

Comment: @user244454: egreg's answer already has that covered.

Comment: @Brian: Haha thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternative path:
$$
\sin a+\cos a=
\sqrt{2}\left(\sin a\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+\cos a\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=
\sqrt{2}\sin\left(a+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\le\sqrt{2}
$$
(and also $\ge-\sqrt{2}$, of course).

However your reasoning is basically correct; only you need to do it backwards:
$$
\sin^2a+2\sin a\cos a+\cos^2a\le2
$$
because $\sin^2a+\cos^2a=1$ and $2\sin a\cos a=\sin 2a\le 1$; therefore
$$
(\sin a+\cos a)^2\le 2
$$
and so
$$
\sin a+\cos a\le \sqrt{2}
$$

Comment: I got it & thanks

Answer (score 4):

If @Zev Chonoles guessed right, you can prove this by computing
$$\max_{x\in [0,2\pi]} \sin x + \cos x$$
The critical points are precisely those where $\cos x - \sin x = 0$ (derivative). These are $x = \frac\pi4$ and $x = \frac{5\pi}4$. Evaluating at those and the boundary points gives
$$\sin \frac\pi4 + \cos \frac\pi4 = \frac1{\sqrt2} + \frac1{\sqrt2} = \sqrt2 \\
\sin \frac{4\pi}4 + \cos \frac{5\pi}4 = -\frac1{\sqrt2} - \frac1{\sqrt 2} = -\sqrt2 \\
\sin 0 + \cos 0 = 0 + 1 = 1\\
\sin 2\pi + \cos 2\pi = 0 + 1 = 1$$
Thus the maximum is $\max(\sqrt 2, -\sqrt 2, 1, 1) = \sqrt2$, wich proves
$$\sin x + \cos x \le \sqrt2 \qquad\forall\ x\in[0,2\pi]$$
Now since the function is $2\pi$-periodic, we can conclude
$$\sin x + \cos x \le \sqrt2 \qquad \forall\ x\in\mathbb R$$